# Computed persisted column does not pick index and shows conversion warning in SQL Server 2016 sp1-cu4

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created PK based on identity column a computed persisted column as

```
('P'+ RIGHT('000000000' + CONVERT([VARCHAR](8), [ID], (0)), (7))) PERSISTED
```

I created both tables, in the same way, a persisted columns. When I tried to join both persisted columns on inner join, it does not pick the index and warning is being shown

> Type conversion expression convert(varchar(8), id, 0) may effect cardinality estimate in version Microsoft SQL Server 2016 -sp1cu4

Table #1:

```
create table dbo.master_designation 
(
    id int identity(1,1) not null,
    dept_code varchar(8) not null,
    user_type_code varchar(8) not null,
    desig_code as ('P'+ RIGHT('0000000' + CONVERT([VARCHAR](8), [ID], (0)), (7))) PERSISTED,
    name varchar(30) not null,
    shortname varchar(30) not null
) on primary
```

Create index:

```
create nonclustered index idx2 
on master_designation (desig_code);
```

Table #2:

```
create table dbo.mapping_employee_designation 
(
    id int identity(1,1) not null,
    emp_code varchar(8) not null,
    dept_code varchar(8) not null,
    desig_code as ('P'+ RIGHT('0000000' + CONVERT([VARCHAR](8), [ID], (0)), (7))) PERSISTED,
    location_code varchar(5) null,
    report_to varchar(8) null,
    active bit not null
) on primary
```

Create index

```
create nonclustered index idx1 
on mapping_employee_designation (desig_code);
```

Comment: Can you share the actual table definition? As posted all we can do is guess or hope the crystal ball sheds some information.

Comment: Based on your explanation I assume you have index on `ID` column, do you have index on computed column ? post the execution plan and table definition

Comment: As an aside, to create an index on a computed column, it does *not* have to be marked `PERSISTED`, unless it involves the imprecise types `float` and `real` or features nondeterministic functions. Your expression is deterministic and requires no persisting.

Comment: There are more than 80 tables having such computed columns based on identity columns. This is ERP database and no indexing is done. Most of the tables have NO primary key and no indexes. Does this a normal practice in ERP database?

Comment: Does knowing whether it is or isn't help you solve your problem in any way? In some sense, yes, lacking keys and indexes is a normal practice in databases set up by people who don't actually know how databases work, since your average database will work just fine without them -- until it becomes big.